# What is Horizon in Horizon: Zero Dawn?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

Usually I don't fret about the game name, but I don't know why, it feels like I missed something in Horizon: Zero Dawn.

In the game, the Zero Dawn project plays a big part, so it explains why it's in the title of the game.

So it feels like I missed why Horizon is in the game's title. From what I've seen, Horizon seems a random word, stuck on the beginning of the games name, and that feels wrong.

So is there any meaning in the word Horizon, in the title Horizon: Zero Dawn?

Comment: I have never seen anything directly stating why the word horizon is in it but I would assume based on the definition of horizon : the limit of a person's mental perception, experience, or interest. its meant to invoke the idea of the experience of figuring out what the zero dawn project is or maybe what the preception of creating something like the zero dawn project could have on a population?

Comment: As far as I know, "Horizon" was the codename before the game was officially announced. Maybe it could be the hypothetical series name, like The Elder Scrolls, and Zero Dawn probably is just the first of them.

Comment: To me "Horizon" is the name of the franchise, meaning future, something being "on the horizon". And this is the "Zero Dawn" chapter of the story. I wouldn't be surprised if a sequel came out with a new subtle, eg "Horizon: Aloy's Journey"...etc

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The lead writer of Horizon: Zero Dawn, Ben McCaw, commented on this during a Q&A session on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/horizon/comments/5zidtl/join_our_ama_with_the_developers_of_horizon_zero/). The choosing of the word "Horizon" was to lay down the setting of a new world to be discovered

> "For us, “Horizon” represents a boundless new world, and also the passage of time (where the Sun rises and sets) that is so fundamental to the setting and story."